# AS3 filereference browse() method does not work in Chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome, filereference

I'm implementing a file uploader in AS3 and came across a problem: the browse() method of a filereference class does not work in Chrome, i.e. the dialog window to select files does not open. This is a definitely a problem with pepper flash player, because when I changed it to the adobe's one in Chrome's plugin settings everything started working normally. Also the swf works fine in firefox and explorer. 
Does anyone know how to get around this bug? Thanks!

Comment: that's weird!. Can you verify the behavior with the embedded example on http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/filereference_class_as3.html? Also, is it possible for you to host an example somewhere and post the link here?

Comment: Are you testing in debug mode? If you are, try doing a release build and seeing if that makes a difference. Pepper Flash has issues with debug mode (among other things. Awful plugin)